Method is Unexpectedly Called in Unity C#
I'm working on an optimization for a learning project where I'm recreating the basic functionality of Minecraft.
I've successfully implemented optimizations for the border and corner cubes of chunks. When the player triggers the chunk generation process, cubes on the borders and corners that are fully covered on all sides are either disabled (if they already exist) or not instantiated (if they are new cubes for a new chunk).
To make the code cleaner, I decided to move the border and corner cube optimizations into separate classes, each inheriting from a MapOptimization script. I started with the BorderOptimization script and used an onIsBorderCube action to trigger the BorderCubeOptimizationSequence. I've subscribed to the onIsBorderCube action in the Start() method of BorderOptimization. While the action is invoked correctly, I'm encountering a NullReferenceException after finishing each valid iterations.
The exception occurs right after the ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcomingChunk method finishes. For some reason, the ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcomingChunk method is being called again, but this time the onIsBorderCube action is null, causing the crash.
MapOptimization script bellow ⬇️
The script is not full, I've removed other things to keep preview brief. If you miss anything let me know and I will add it.
public class MapOptimization : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected Action<Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData>, CubeData, Border> onIsBorderCube;

    private void ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcommingChunk(Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData, Vector3 centerOfNewChunk)
    {
        centerOfXNegativeNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(centerOfNewChunk.x - mapGenerator.gridSize.x, centerOfNewChunk.y, centerOfNewChunk.z);
        centerOfXPositiveNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(centerOfNewChunk.x + mapGenerator.gridSize.x, centerOfNewChunk.y, centerOfNewChunk.z);
        centerOfZNegativeNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(centerOfNewChunk.x, centerOfNewChunk.y, centerOfNewChunk.z - mapGenerator.gridSize.z);
        centerOfZPositiveNeighbourChunk = new Vector3(centerOfNewChunk.x, centerOfNewChunk.y, centerOfNewChunk.z + mapGenerator.gridSize.z);

        XNegativeCorner = centerOfNewChunk.x - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) + 1.0f;
        XPositiveCorner = centerOfNewChunk.x + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) - 1.0f;
        ZNegativeCorner = centerOfNewChunk.z - Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) + 1.0f;
        ZPositiveCorner = centerOfNewChunk.z + Mathf.Ceil((float)mapGenerator.gridSize.x / 2.0f) - 1.0f;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Vector3, CubeData> newCubeData in newChunkFieldData)
        {
            OptimizeDataOfNewChunk(newCubeData.Value, centerOfNewChunk, newChunkFieldData);
        }
    }

    private void OptimizeDataOfNewChunk(CubeData newCubeData, Vector3 centerOfNewChunk, Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData)
    {
        Border newChunkBorder = Border.Null;
        if (isCubeAtBorder(newCubeData.position, ref newChunkBorder))
        {
            Corner newCubeCorner = Corner.Null;
            if (isNewCubeAtCorner(newCubeData, ref newCubeCorner))
            {
                CornerCubeOptimizationSequence(newCubeData, centerOfNewChunk, newChunkBorder, newCubeCorner);
            }
            else
            {
                onIsBorderCube(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData, newChunkBorder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DeactiavateSurroundedCubeData(newCubeData, newChunkFieldData);
        }
    }
}


BorderOptimization script bellow ⬇️
The script is not full, I've removed other things to keep it preview brief. If you miss anything let me know and I will add it.
public class BorderOptimization : MapOptimization 
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("onIsBorder is subscribbed");
        onIsBorderCube += BorderCubeOptimizationSequence;
    }

    private void BorderCubeOptimizationSequence(Dictionary<Vector3, CubeData> newChunkFieldData, CubeData newCubeData, Border newChunkBorder)
    {
        Border neighbourChunkBorder = Border.Null;
        Vector3 neighbourCubePosition = Vector3.zero;
        Vector3 neighbourChunkCenter = Vector3.zero;

        SetNeighborChunkValues(newChunkBorder, newCubeData.position, ref neighbourChunkBorder, ref neighbourCubePosition, ref neighbourChunkCenter);

        if (!DoesNeighborChunkExist(neighbourChunkCenter))
        {
            return;
        }

        Dictionary<Vector3, CubeParameters> neighbourChunkField = mapGenerator.dictionaryOfCentersWithItsChunkField[neighbourChunkCenter];
        // Return if New Cube in New Chunk isn't surrounded with cubes from each sides
        if (!IsBorderCubeSurrounded<CubeData, CubeParameters>(newChunkFieldData, newCubeData.position, neighbourChunkField, neighbourCubePosition, newChunkBorder))
        {
            return;
        }
        newCubeData.isCubeDataSurrounded = true;

        // Return if Neighbor Cube in Neighbor Chunk isn't surrounded with cubes from each sides
        if (!IsBorderCubeSurrounded<CubeParameters, CubeData>(neighbourChunkField, neighbourCubePosition, newChunkFieldData, newCubeData.position, neighbourChunkBorder))
        {
            return;
        }
        neighbourChunkField[neighbourCubePosition].cubeInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

The issue I’m facing isn't that the onIsBorderCube action is throwing a NullReferenceException, but that the ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcommingChunk method is being called an extra time, which it shouldn't be.
Steps I've Taken:

I reverted to a previous implementation, and in that version, the extra call to ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcommingChunk doesn't occur. This suggests that the problem might not lie in the onIsBorderCube action itself, but elsewhere in the code.

I’ve reviewed all references to ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcommingChunk and confirmed it should only be called once within the corresponding script.

While debugging, I noticed that when the method is called that extra time, the debugger doesn't return to the place where ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcommingChunk has been been called.

I’ve also checked the call stack for both valid and invalid iterations of this method call. Oddly, the call stacks look identical for both cases, despite one resulting in an extra invocation.


Valid iteration
enter image description here
Invalid iteration
enter image description here
I suppose that it might be occurring due to Order of Execution for Event Functions, but struggling to find the reason why.
Here I'm sending a video how it looks like when I'm debugging the issue.

Although you mentioned that the call stacks for invalid and valid iterations look the same, there may be some subtle differences that cause the problem. Try adding more debug logs at different points in the call stack to track the call flow more finely, such as the value of centerOfNewChunk, or log each time onIsBorderCube is triggered to find the root cause of the extra calls. You can do this by using Debug.Log in the method.

What does your MapGenerator script looks like? Is this script on the same object or do you reference some other script? If it's on the same object, yes you would run into potential ordering issues since you rely on Start of your BorderOptimization script has run before the Start of your MapGenerator script. You probably want to subscribe in Awake and not in Start. Why do you use an event in the first place since you seem to use inheritance? An abstract method would make more sense since your base class depends on the method being implemented.

Yes, Bunny83, I have the BorderOptimization script attached to the same object as MapOptimization. When I removed it and debugged the code with the onIsBorderCube action commented out, the ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcomingChunk method was no longer called twice. It will take me some time to fully understand why this happens, but once I do, I will post a detailed explanation on the topic. If I determine that it's relevant, I will also consider making this method abstract. Thank you for your help!

@Oz4kk Hi, I'm wondering if there are any updates to your statement about posting detailed explanation on this topic, and if so, you could post this as an answer.

Hello! Apologies for the delayed response. I believe I’ve identified a potential solution to the issue. The main challenges I’ve encountered relate to Unity's execution order and some misunderstandings I had about how inheritance functions in this context.
As I find the proper solution to my issue I will write an answer, yet I don't have a sufficient context on it.

The issue was in my misunderstanding how inheritance works.
If I put Base script and Derived script on the same gameobject, then there will be created two instances of Base script and ProcessAllCubeDataOfUpcomingChunk will be called twice (once per instance).
